# Mining Twitter Data to find insights about a user?

Tags: twitter, nlp, data-mining, text-mining

I am starting with a project that shall be analyzing a user's interests and engagement through his twitter profile. What sort of metrics can be obtained by analyzing his twitter data ? The things I feel can be done include:

1. Topics that the user talks about the most (his interests) by analyzing his tweets.
2. The communities he is active in (by analyzing hash-tags)
3. The mood of the person by classifying tweets as positive / negative.

Other trends could include his outreach and the people he interacts with generally.

Are there other interesting aspects that can be derived about a person through his profile ? [Twitalyzer](http://twitalyzer.com) seems to also show the age groups the person interacts with most but I don't have much clue as to how to do that.

Also I plan to develop the project as a webapp. I plan to use PHP for making the crawler. For the mining part, would you suggest sticking to PHP or recommend other another technology / language ?

Some projects I have been looking at for inspiration include:

- [Personas](http://personas.media.mit.edu/)
- [TweetPsych](http://tweetpsych.com/)
- [Twitalyzer](http://twitalyzer.com)

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider the communities he's in. 
By extracting the mentions he makes (or the ones he's mentioned in) and producing a graph will give you plenty of insight on the user and the people he's interested in. Especially if you introduce the notion of centrality in your work...

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the brand loyality of a particular person particularly if the person is influential can be really insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand the scope a bit beyond Twitter, if the insights about the user is top priority.

You could for example assume the twitter tag is a username they use on other services, perhaps even for common email address distributors (gmail, yahoo). If they have other account names in their bio you could probe them to see if they have an account on platforms that are less restrictive about user information.

If the main focus was to specifically use the Twitter feed of the user, I guess I'll leave this as an expansion idea.